# Rails: errors in production vs development

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In Rails, is there a way to display different error messages on a production rails server (a nice graphic) vs a development server (detailed error information, stack trace, etc.)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found one [solution](http://e-haitham.blogspot.com/2008/06/rails-exception-handling-has-never-been.html).  In ApplicationController, add:

```
rescue_from Exception, :with => :rescue_all_exceptions if RAILS_ENV == 'production'

def rescue_all_exceptions(exception)
  case exception
    # do production-ey exception stuff
  end
end
```

I'd be interested to hear other options...